# Deleting a record that doesn't exist from MS Access Database using .net

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio, ms-access

the below function deletes the row from my MS Access database. Everything is working fine except that if I enter a  'txtRiskid.Text' which doesn't exist it runs the else statement. How can I catch this in this this if statement, so if I were to enter a 'txtRiskid.Text' that doesn't exist it would tell me it doesn't exist via  a message, similar to what I wrote if it is left empty.

Delete button coding:

```
Private Sub Deletebtn_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Deletebtn.Click
    If txtRiskid.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Please enter a existing 'Risk ID' to delete the specific record from the database", 0, "Warning")
    Else
        Dim Deletequery As String = "delete from Risk_Register where ID=@ID"
        Runquery(Deletequery)
        MsgBox("The record has been Deleted successfully from the database.", 0, "Information")
    End If
End Sub
```

Runquery coding:

```
Public Sub Runquery(ByVal query As String)

    con = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\ahmed\OneDrive\Desktop\ProjectDatabase2003.mdb")
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(query, con)

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", txtRiskid.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Risk_Name", txtRiskname.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Risk_Description", txtRiskdescription.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Owner", txtOwner.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Control", txtControl.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Probability", txtProbability.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Impact", txtImpact.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Risk_Level", txtRisklevel.Text)

    con.Open()
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    con.Close()

End Sub
```

Comment: What should happen if it doesn't exist? Your DELETE query will execute just fine and it will delete no records in that case. In your position, I would worry more if the user entered an invalid ID (assuming that ID is numeric and users can enter "ABC" as an ID value, in which case the query execution will throw an exception. Also, using `AddWithValue` is not such a great option to specify command parameters in ADO.NET. ([`AddWithValue` is evil](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/).)

Comment: The other bad idea is to store the Connection object instead of declaring it in-place, when needed. Why do you keep that `con` object as a Field instead of writing `Dim con = New OleDbConnection(...)` (or, better, `Using con = New OleDbConnection(...) [...] End Using`)? - The Command object is also disposable. Another not so great idea is to try and use a single method to delete rows and possibly other operations using the same construction. You could use a DataAdapter and QueryBuilder...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ExecuteNonQuery()` returns the number of rows affected see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.executenonquery
Return it from your `Runquery` sub and check in the `Deletebtn_Click_1` handler.

Kind of

```
Private Sub Deletebtn_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Deletebtn.Click
    If txtRiskid.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Please enter a existing 'Risk ID' to delete the specific record from the database", 0, "Warning")
    Else
        Dim Deletequery As String = "delete from Risk_Register where ID=@ID"
        If Runquery(Deletequery) > 0 Then
            MsgBox("The record has been Deleted successfully from the database.", 0, "Information")
        Else
            MsgBox("The record doesn't exist in the database.", 0, "Information")
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

and

```
Public Function Runquery(ByVal query As String) As Integer

    con = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\ahmed\OneDrive\Desktop\ProjectDatabase2003.mdb")
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(query, con)
    Dim count As Integer
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", txtRiskid.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Risk_Name", txtRiskname.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Risk_Description", txtRiskdescription.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Owner", txtOwner.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Control", txtControl.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Probability", txtProbability.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Impact", txtImpact.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Risk_Level", txtRisklevel.Text)

    con.Open()
    count = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    con.Close()
    Return count
End Function
```

Comment: How would I be able to integrate this into my coding. Is it not possible to catch this error inside of the if statement I made by adding a new else/elseif layer to prevent this error?

Comment: Thank you so much.